# Algolia not indexing any product on Magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento, algolia

I've installed the Algolia extension on my Magento website, configured the CRON job, enabled the queue and set up all credentials but Algolia still doesn't index my store. There aren't any products on search results, regardless of what you type. My store is NOT managing stock, as it is a catalog website.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hello, did you check the indexing documentation? https://community.algolia.com/magento/doc/m1/indexing/ All the information about the indexing should be there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Can you post the question to https://discourse.algolia.com/c/magento? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, no problem Jan! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1.Please Enable Algolia log and check if there is any error.

2.check your products are indexed on  Algolia dashborad Index section or not .
if products are Indexed there it means algolia search indexing working.

3.May be you have not entered the correct credentials or not configured the extension correctly.

4.Please also check if all products are  set In stock (Stock may be the issue if products are not indexed without any error).